# Escaping Characters Regex

Tags: python

I've been picking my brain on how to get the 2 integers from the following string:

```
:{\"page_type\":16,\"actor_id\":100010050258799,\"story_id\":166366493708358,\"a
```

I can write the regex fine, but it's escaping that it causing some headaches.

What characters do I need to escape to get this to work with `re.match`

For example, how do I place the `"` in the following:

```
re.match("actor_id\\")
```

I've tried `\\\\""` to no avail.

It's a JSON string, but JSON decode is not an option in this case because it's deep within sourcecode that's not easily accessible by traversing the DOM. So I'm stuck with regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might want to look at the documentation for [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) because it states that:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression

NOTE: the BEGINNING.

you can instead be using `re.findall' to tokenize each key to their int. IE:

```
>>> s = ':{\"page_type\":16,\"actor_id\":100010050258799,\"story_id\":166366493708358,\"a'
>>> re.findall('"([^"]+)":(\d+)',s)
[('page_type', '16'), ('actor_id', '100010050258799'), ('story_id', '166366493708358')]
>>> 
>>> d = dict(re.findall('"([^"]+)":(\d+)',s))
>>> d
{'actor_id': '100010050258799', 'page_type': '16', 'story_id': '166366493708358'}
```

note the pattern:

```
"([^"]+)":(\d+)
" #matches `"` char
 ([^"]+) #matches anything EXCEPT `"` char, and captures in a group
        ": #matches `":` chars
          (\d+) #matches 1 or more digits and captures in a group
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply treat everything non-numeric the same:

```
re.match(r'[^\d]+\d+[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)', thestring)
```

This matches but does not capture the first number (`16`), then
captures the other two. It's easy to insert things like `actor_id`
if you need it to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about this one.

```
>>> import re
>>> x = ':{\"page_type\":16,\"actor_id\":100010050258799,\"story_id\":166366493708358,\"a'
>>> re.search(
        '\\"page_type\\":([0-9]+),'
        '\\"actor_id\\":([0-9]+)',
        x
    ).groups()
('16', '100010050258799')
```

<strike>I'm more interested in why JSON decoding is not an option for you? Are you getting a special exception or is this some psuedo-JSON format?</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `'` instead of `"`. You don't have to escape double quote character if you use single quote. This worked for me:

```
s = ":{\"page_type\":16,\"actor_id\":100010050258799,\"story_id"
m = re.search('actor_id":(\\d+),',s)
print(m.group(1))
```